# Python3.4 installed on 64 bit machine is indicated as 'on win32', what does this mean?

Tags: windows-7, python-3.4

I only lately realized that my Python3.4 installation on Windows 7-64bit which I have been using successfully (with many 64 bit add-ons) says 'on win32'.  What does this mean?  Is this a problem?

C:>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Nope, not a problem.  Win32 is the standard Windows API, as distinct from other APIs such as, for example, Win16, POSIX, or the Windows kernel API.  64-bit Windows did not introduce a new API, so there is no Win64, just 64-bit Win32.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed response. It is much appreciated.